# Android getapplication() data

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

I am using `getHotelName()` and `setHotelName()` to store data in the application and then access it. In my main activity that is categorized as Launcher both the methods and the `getApplication()` works in this activity. But when I try to access the getApplication from a different activity which is called from the main activity it gives a force close error.

This is my manifest file :

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_short_name" android:name="RestaurantNetwork" android:allowClearUserData="true" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black" >

    <activity android:name="RestaurantActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name="NetworkCommunication"></activity>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

</application>
```

In the main activity

```
RestaurantNetwork application = (RestaurantNetwork) getApplication();
application.setHotelName(this.hotelname.getText().toString());
Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), NetworkCommunication.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

In the NetworkCommunication activity

```
public class NetworkCommunication extends Activity {
RestaurantNetwork application = (RestaurantNetwork) getApplication();
String hotelname = application.getHotelName().toString();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it using intent.extra, yes i had to get rid of the getApplication(). Would still like to know why there was an error in the prev method

in my main activity

```
    this.hotelname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.HotelName);

//RestaurantNetwork application = (RestaurantNetwork)getApplication();
//application.setHotelName(this.hotelname.getText().toString());

 Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), NetworkCommunication.class);
 intent.putExtra("hotelName",this.hotelname.getText().toString());
 startActivity(intent);
```

in my second activity

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.searchresults);

        String value = null;

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(extras !=null)
        {
          value = extras.getString("hotelName");
        }

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),value, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```